# Apache poi - when reading a excel file, how to know which cell was in error

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

i'm trying to find a way to know the cellAddress which was in error while reading the excel file. How can I know which cell was in error without recording at each read the cellAddress ? And how to continue reading the line to find out if other errors are present ?

My code :

```
final Person person = new Person();
List<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();

int lastColumn = Math.max(row.getLastCellNum(), 43);

for (int colNum = 2; colNum < lastColumn; colNum++) {
    Cell cell = row.getCell(colNum, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
    if ((cell == null) || cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING &&
            cell.getStringCellValue().trim().isEmpty()) {
        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
    }
    cells.add(cell);
}

// I memorize by incrementing each time the value of the cellAddress in case there's an error
CellAddress cellAddress = null;
try {
    cellAddress = cells.get(1).getAddress();
    person.setTitle(cells.get(1).getStringCellValue());
    cellAddress = cells.get(2).getAddress();
    person.setLastName(cells.get(2).getStringCellValue());
    cellAddress = cells.get(3).getAddress();
    person.setFirstName(cells.get(3).getStringCellValue());
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {

    LOG.info("Cell in error : {}", cellAddress);
}
```

Thanks for your help. I'm beginner in java.

Comment: Check each cell until you find one with a cell type of error?

Comment: The errors that I get are not considered as cell type_error but are related to the mapping like :
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell

Comment: Well then don't do that! Check the cell type before you read it, or use `DataFormatter` or something. Either way, read the Apache POI docs, it's all covered there!